# R: Create a color vector for specific values from a range

Tags: r

I want to create a vector of colors to then apply it to a barplot. I have created a color range:

```
color.function <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))
```

And then I would like to get the specific colors for specific values contained in a range. For example, let's say that I want the color range to span -10 to 10. Then I want to get the colors for -7, -4.5 and 2 (for example).

How could I do that? I have tried this:

```
col.seq <- seq(-10, 10, 0.1) 
cuts <- cut(c(-7,-4.5,2), breaks = length(col.seq)) 
colors <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))(length(col.seq)) 
levels(colors) <- cuts 
colors
```

but it seems to just give a color per break on my palette.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You could use `cut` to create the groups

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Have you tried something? If yes, can you edit your question to show the code, and the problems it has (how it differs from expected output, or the error message it gives)?

Comment: I have added what I tried, but I think there is something that I don't understand here

Comment: I have never used "cut" before

Comment: I think you should be providing the `breaks` argument as `-7, -4.5, 2`\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get correct colour for you numeric value you need to find it's idex in the sequence vector you started with.

You can get it with rounding and `which`:

```
color.function <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))

col.seq <- round(seq(-10, 10, 0.1), 1)
colors <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "white", "red"))(length(col.seq)) 

x <- 6.5323
x.map <- round(x, 1)
x.index <- which(col.seq == x.map)
colors[x.index]
# [1] "#FF5959" 

x <- 1.7323
x.map <- round(x, 1)
x.index <- which(col.seq == x.map)
colors[x.index]
# [1] "#FFD3D3"
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to modify your solution to accomotate a vector of "x" values